# Taking and renaming a created file via a pipe or other means in bash

Tags: bash, ubuntu, mv, youtube-dl

First ever question:

Im quite new to this scripting business but I've been trying to automate downloading and renaming youtube videos using youtube-dl. I'm really just doing this as a technical exercise to learn a bit more about bash scripting.

The command I'm using is:

```
youtube-dl -il "<Youtube URL>" --extract-audio --audio-format "mp3" --audio-quality "192k"
```

(which will download individual videos or take a playlist and download all files) and this creates a file with the following format (example):

```
Zedd - Spectrum (feat. Matthew Koma) (Culture_Code_Remix)-LCNwQVRN34.mp3
```

Where the last reference part of the youtube URL is on the end.

I have written a script to mass-rename all the files which works and is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in *.mp3 ; do
   j=`echo $i | awk -F"-" '{print $1 "-" $2}'`
   mv "$i" "$j"
done
```

basically it just cuts off the last piece, my question is how could I put this in a different format so that I can either pipe it on the end or incorporate it and the first command in to a single script so I can automate the whole process?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just pass another file name template to youtube-dl with the `-o` option:

```
youtube-dl -i "<Youtube URL>" -o "%(title)s.%(ext)s" \
            --extract-audio --audio-format "mp3" --audio-quality "192k"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to run the for loop on the play-list file and use the iteration variable as input for youtube-dl and then do the mv processing.